# Apache stops responding

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver

I have wampserver 2.4 installed on a computer and Apache stops responding to web requests.  If I try to access the site nothing happens.  It will work fine for a day, or about 69 hours in this last case and then, seemingly randomly, it stops.

It can always be resolved by restarting the apache service.

I don't see anything in the apache_error.log file either.

What else can I do to find the cause of this problem?

Comment: When Apache goes AWOL like this, and you call netstat -an, do you see the connection from the client in the ESTABLISHED state?  In other words, is the traffic from the client getting to the TCP stack on the server?

Comment: It looks like there were about 40 connections on port 80, most of them had the state "CLOSE_WAIT" Would that cause apache to not be able to respond?

Comment: no, but they should not be sticking around for very long.  CLOSE_WAIT state means that the server has received a FIN from the client and the socket is waiting for the application (apache) to issue a close() system call on the socket.  If that isn't happening, then something funky is going on inside Apache and over a period of time you will run out of socket descriptors and hang.  But don't assume a bug: it could just as easily be that Apache is tied up doing something (say, a module/webapp writing something to a database that is sloow).

Answer (score 1):

Check your `httpd.conf` file and if these entries do not exist try adding them

```
AcceptFilter http none
EnableSendfile Off
EnableMMAP off
```

This has fixed this issue in the past.

Comment: I have silmiler issue, can you please explain how this abouve code can fix the issue, Thanks in Advance :)